# Why there is no Error "Add unimplemented methods" for implementation(Eclipse)

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

This code show the error to add unimplemented methods.

```
public class Child implements IResponse
```

but this is not showing the error.

```
public class Child extends Parent implements IResponse
```

Could you explain why the second snippet was not enforced to implement the methods from Interface?

Is there anyway to enforce this for multiple inheritance?

Comment: Please do not anyhow down vote. People will ask when they do not know about it. Stackoverflow exists to help people. But if you want to down vote, you should at least give a reason. I believe it was not done by people with high reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods that `IResponse` declares are defined in `Parent` ?

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the code for `Parent` and `Child`, I can only guess, but I'd say it is that `Parent` implements the necessary methods for `IResponse`.

Comment: Thx for answering Ted, but Jigar Joshi answered it first. And I up voted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Interface` contains all `abstract` methods, which are to be implemented by the implementing class.
2. If `Parent` class is an `abstract` class, then the `abstract` methods should be implemented by the sub class.

You get the `add unimplemented methods` error only in the above two cases, where implementing the abstract methods is mandatory.
So in your case, if `Parent` is not an `abstract` class, you wont get the `add unimplemented methods` error.