# If a child class and parent class both implement the same interface, why is it only the parent class that is forced to add unimplemented methods?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have three classes below `AnimalActions` an interface, and two other classes `Animal` which is the parent of `Human`

The `AnimalActions` interface is as follows:

```
public interface AnimalActions {

  public String greeting(); // how an animal says hello

  public String angryAction(); // how an animal says "im angry"

  public String happyAction(); // how an animal says "im happy"
}
```

When I have the class `Animal` implement `AnimalActions` I get a compiler error, forcing me to add the unimplemented methods, so the Class needs to look like this:

```
public class Animal implements AnimalActions {

  @Override
  public String greeting() {
    return "default greeting";
  }

  @Override
  public String angryAction() {
    return "default angry action";
  }

  @Override
  public String happyAction() {
    return "default happy";
  }

}
```

But when I then make a class `Human` that extends `Animal` and implements `AnimalActions` there is no compiler error forcing me to override the methods. This is perfectly acceptable to Eclipse.

```
public class Human extends Animal implements AnimalActions{

}
```

I can, however, add the unimplemented methods and change them from `Animal`, if I want to. I'm just not forced to do it.

The weird thing is that if I remove `extends Animal` from this class, then I am forced to add unimplemented methods. Why would I not be forced to add the unimplemented methods?

Every time I think I get a grasp on OOP I get confused about something weird like this. Is it total "nonsense" to have both a parent and child class implementing the same interface? Would it be better to just have `extends Animal` only?

Thanks a lot. I know this questions been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714190/why-there-is-no-error-add-unimplemented-methods-for-implementationeclipse) is the same question, but there was no code to go with the question or answer so it was a bit abstract for me.

Comment: Animal already implements AnimalActions, so any class that extends Animal does not need to implement the AnimalActions methods. To be more obvious, you could simply use `public class Human extends Animal{` because you do not need to implement the already implemented AnimalActions of the parent class in the child class, but if you wanted, then you could override them.

Comment: Untrue. The parent class can be `abstract`, in which case it is the child class that is forced to implement the methods, unless it is also `abstract` of course. Any non-abstract class has to implement all the abstract methods it inherits from its parent or interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply because the child gets access to all parent methods, as well as the overriden methods from the Interface.
You can again override these methods, but then you need to call `super.someMethod()` if you need to call the parents implementation.